# Counting the number of level changes of an attribute

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I have a data frame like

```
ID  YEAR_MONTH  ATT_1   ATT_2
1   201301        Y     1
1   201302        Y     1
1   201302        N     0
1   201302        Y     0
1   201303        N     1
3   201301        N     1
3   201302        N     0
3   201302        Y     0
3   201302        Y     1
3   201303        Y     1
```

I want a final dataframe which will look like

```
ID  YEAR_MONTH  YEARMONTH_LAG1  ATT1_CHNG   ATT2_CHNG
1   201301           NA           NA          NA
1   201302           201301       0           0
1   201303           201302       2           1
3   201301           NA           NA          NA
3   201302           201301       0           0
3   201303           201302       1           1
```

> Note:
>
> 1. 'YEARMONTH_LAG1 ' is the previous month corresponding to the current month. E.g., if YEAR_MONTH == 201301 then YEARMONTH_LAG1 = NA
>      (as there is no record for 201212, and there is none in my data as all
>      starts from 201201). Similarly if YEAR_MONTH == 201302 then
>      YEARMONTH_LAG1 = 201301.
> 2. ATT1_CHNG is the number of times the level has changed (i.e., from Y to N and vice-verse) for 'ATT_1' in the previous month (i.e., in
>      YEARMONTH_LAG1)
> 3. ATT2_CHNG is the number of times the level has changed (i.e., from 0 to 1 and vice-verse) for ATT_2 in the previous month

How can this be done in R?

Comment: Please read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

df$ATT_1_New <- ifelse(df$ATT_1 == "Y", 1,0)

df %.% 
  group_by(ID, YEAR_MONTH) %.% 
  mutate(ATT_1_CHNG = sum(abs(diff(ATT_1_New))),
         ATT_2_CHNG = sum(abs(diff(ATT_2)))) %.%
  group_by(ID, add=FALSE) %.%
  mutate(YEARMONTH_LAG1 = lag(YEAR_MONTH, 1),
         ATT_1_CHNG = lag(ATT_1_CHNG,1),
         ATT_2_CHNG = lag(ATT_2_CHNG,1)) %.%
  group_by(ID, YEAR_MONTH, add = FALSE) %.%
  summarize(YEARMONTH_LAG1 = YEARMONTH_LAG1[1],
            ATT_1_CHNG =  ATT_1_CHNG[1], 
            ATT_2_CHNG =  ATT_2_CHNG[1])


#  ID YEAR_MONTH YEARMONTH_LAG1 ATT_1_CHNG ATT_2_CHNG
#1  1     201301             NA         NA         NA
#2  1     201302         201301          0          0
#3  1     201303         201302          2          1
#4  3     201301             NA         NA         NA
#5  3     201302         201301          0          0
#6  3     201303         201302          1          1
```

Comment: @beginnerR this works fine. But, what if I have several columns for which I want to do this, then it will be really tiresome to individually enter each column name for each operation. Is there an alternate way of doing it (something like a loop or something)?

Comment: @darkage consider accepting a correct answer to your question to acknowledge the time others spend dealing with it. You may want to have a look at the new [`summarize_each` function](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) in dplyr 0.2 which you have to install from GitHub, not CRAN. Perhaps this does what you want.